# get notified if objects is there in a particular folders of a s3 bucket for more than 7 hours

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, notifications, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a lambda to process the files in a folder of a s3 bucket. I would like to setup an alarm/notification if objects are in the folders for more than 7 hours and not processed by the lambda

Comment: What does the lambda do? One it processed the file, will it write a new version of the file to S3 (same bucket) or does the file get deleted after the lambda processed it? Do you need to keep the file once it has been processed?

Comment: @st.huber lambda will process the file and move to archive. We had an issue the customer uploaded the data but Lambda did not process the files and the objects stayed in the folder without being processed. So I need to create a notification to know if the file is processed by the lambda after uploading or not, threshold time should be 7 hours.

Comment: How does the customer upload the data to S3?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **tags** of objects in S3, have something like **tag name Processed : true or false** changed by your lambda processor.

Then in your another scheduled lambda you can check the creation object if > 7h and processed : false (that means not processed by the lambda), if found you create a notification in SNS

Comment: Objects does not have tags. The customer will upload the data and we have a lambda to process it and archive. I want to create a notification if the lambda did not process the file for 7 hours after data ingestion to the folder in s3

Answer (score 0):

Set [object expiration](https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-object-expiration/) to 7 hours for the S3 bucket. Then have a lambda get [triggered by the delete event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/NotificationHowTo.html#notification-how-to-event-types-and-destinations). The lambda can be one that notifies you and saves the file into another bucket or forwards it to your original lambda. The lambda triggered could be the one that should have been triggered when uploading the object.

Alternatively, you can add tags to the uploaded files. A tag could be `ttl: <date-to-delete>`. You have a CloudWatch scheduled event that runs a lambda, for instance every hour, and checks for all objects in the S3 bucket whether the `ttl`-tag's value is older than the current time.

Personally, I would go with the first approach as it's more event driven and less scheduled processing.

On another note, it's rather strange that the lambda doesn't get triggered for some S3 objects. I don't know how you deploy your Lambda and configure the trigger to S3. If you're using [serverless](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/s3) or [CDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/getting_started.html) I don't see how your lambda doesn't get triggered for every uploaded file with a configuration similar to the following:

```yaml
// serverless example
functions:
  users:
    handler: users.handler
    events:
      - s3:
          bucket: photos
          event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
          rules:
            - prefix: uploads/
            - suffix: .jpg
```

In this example the *users* lambda gets triggered for every jpg file that gets created in *photos/uploads*.

Comment: I believe Object expiration will delete the objects after the time. I checked that lambda is processing the file and moving it to another folder called "Archive" so the idea could be like we compare both folders and see if the files are moved to the archive after 7 hours. how can we do this?

Comment: The object expiration will do what you configure it to do. This can be that you delete the file, change the files storage type ... I am pretty sure you can still access the object on S3 when the lambda gets triggered through `s3:ObjectRemoved`